# Did Captain America: Civil War intentionally reference LOST?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, marvel, captain-america-civil-war, lost

*LOST* features Room 23,

> a containment room where a single prisoner is strapped down in a chair and brainwashed.

*Captain America: Civil War* features Deck 23,

> a containment device where a single prisoner, Bucky, is strapped down in a chair and brainwashed.

To me, these seem a little too similar to be a total coincidence. Has anyone associated with *Civil War* mentioned if this was an intentional reference?

Comment: More likely a reference to the [D23 fan club/expo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D23_%28Disney%29).

Comment: [Seems like a really common trope to me](https://www.google.com/search?q=brainwash+chair&tbm=isch)

Comment: @Izkata While the trope itself is common, the fact that they both had "23" in their names is what made them seem related.

Comment: Ironically enough, in *LOST*, Room 23 was in the *Hydra* compound.

Comment: That's only ironic if your name is Alanis Morrissette.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it was possibly a reference to the [D23 (Disney)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D23_%28Disney%29) fan club.

The container name was Deck 23

[image]

But as you can see from the image D was highlighted to make it D23.The *LOST* room number reference seems completely coincidental. Even [screenrant](http://screenrant.com/captain-america-civil-war-movie-easter-eggs/?view=all) speculated the same ( Refer Easter egg no 17).

By Jim Frye from  [d23.com](https://d23.com/a-special-d23-shout-out-in-captain-america-civil-war/?share_token=0852f67040):

> Marvel’s Captain America: Civil War is shaping up to be one of the
>   biggest films of the summer, bringing together Captain America and
>   Iron Man in a battle of wills—and fists! But D23 fans watching the
>   film will get a special treat—an exclusive D23 Easter Egg! Kevin
>   Feige, producer and president, Marvel Studios, is a Disney super-fan,
>   not to mention a big fan of D23. He showed his love during the Captain
>   America: Civil War sneak peek at D23 Expo last year by pointing out a
>   special “Easter egg” in the film: During a scene where Sebastian
>   Stan’s character, Bucky Barnes, aka The Winter Soldier, is being
>   interrogated, the letter “D” and the numbers “23” are prominently
>   displayed on the metallic doors to the room where Bucky is being held.
>   So we asked Feige, is that something that’s actually in the film, or
>   was it created just for D23 Expo? “That’s in the movie, baby!”
>   exclaims Feige, saying it was a deliberate shout-out to D23 fans.
>   “That’s exactly what it was,” he says. “That’s why we showed it to
>   them.” Be on the lookout for this cool D23 Easter Egg when Captain
>   America: Civil War opens on May 6.

Comment: Of note, LOST is an ABC production. ABC is owned by Disney, but the 23 in club D23 is a reference to the year 1923, when Disney was founded as a company.

Comment: After a while (or if you can find explicit proof of your D23 theory), I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @RogueJedi Fair enough, i don't have any official words on it yet.

Comment: If you "don't have any official words on it yet" then maybe consider changing "surely" to "possibly" or something.

Comment: @RedCaio done ;)

Comment: @AnkitSharma here is your proof: https://d23.com/a-special-d23-shout-out-in-captain-america-civil-war/

Comment: @PaulL can't see as I am not a member and they don't make me buy free membership as India is not listed.

Comment: Okay, that's annoying.  When clicking the link from a google search for "civil war d23 easter egg", the page renders fine.  When you go to it directly, it makes you log in.  Ridiculous.  Not sure how to link to it in this case then.

Comment: How about if I use this "share token"?  Does it let you see this? https://d23.com/a-special-d23-shout-out-in-captain-america-civil-war/?share_token=0852f67040

Comment: @PaulL Great, thanks for your help.